# Ver unidades de red en VB6

Tags: vb6

Estimadxs, buenas tardes, me comunico a razón de preguntarles sobre ¿Cómo puedo hacer para ver las unidades de red? La cosa va así, tengo varios proyectos en VB6 en una unidad de red. A estos proyectos, hasta hace un tiempo podía ejecutarlos sin mayor problema alguno. Ya no se cuándo fue la última vez que los pude ejecutar desde la unidad de red. El caso es que hoy quise ejecutarlos y pues sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
No se ha encontrado la ruta: 'S:\Ruta\ruta\archivo.vbp'
```

Del mismo modo, no puedo ver mis unidades de red si intento abrir los proyectos desde el VB6:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto la imagen de la consola utilizando el comando `net use` para mostrar las unidades de red:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y adjunto imagen de que desde el explorador de archivos puedo verla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo mi figuran mis carpetas comunes (Descargas/Imágenes/Documentos/etc) y las tres unidades físicas C/E/DVD. ¿Alguno podrá decirme qué debería de hacer para poder ver las unidades de red a la hora de querer abrir proyectos desde el VB6? Aclaro que tengo W10

Comment: No parece ser un problema de VB ni un tema para tratar en el sitio ¿Tienes algún administrador de redes en tu trabajo a quién consultar?  ¿Puedes acceder a esas carpetas desde el explorador de archivos? Revisa el comando `net use`

Comment: Si, de hecho puedo ver todas las PC de la red como también las unidades de red. Incluso con el comando puedo verlas. He adjuntado las imágenes mostrando lo que mencionas tanto del explorador de archivos como desde cmd @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Por lo que pude encontrar es un problema común, [aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drives-not-available-from-elevated-command) hay un reporte de Microsoft donde se mencionan 2 métodos para arreglarlo.

Pero al seguir investigando se menciona que el segundo método es el que corrige el problema en la mayoría de los casos.

## Detalles para configurar la entrada del Registro EnableLinkedConnections

1. En el Editor del Registro, busque y haga clic en la siguiente subclave del Registro:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

2. Haga clic con el botón derecho en Configuración, seleccione Nuevo y, a continuación, seleccione Valor DWORD (32 bits).
3. Asigne a la nueva entrada del Registro el nombre EnableLinkedConnections.
4. Haga doble clic en la entrada del Registro EnableLinkedConnections .
5. En el cuadro de diálogo Editar valor DWORD , escriba 1 en el campo Datos de valor y, a continuación, seleccione Aceptar.
6. Cierre el Editor del Registro y reinicie el equipo.